# Will noise be an issue when joining two rooms with a circulating fan?

Tags: walls, air-conditioning, sound-proofing

The plan is to join two adjacent rooms with an exhaust fan. One has air conditioner, the other does not. A handyman will drill a square hole into the wall, and then attach the fan. The goal is to cool both rooms when the air conditioner is open.

Since we live in an area where this setup is rare, we don't have any idea if noise will be an issue. The person in the other room plays music at night. If noise will be a factor, is there a method on how to minimize the sound? Will the addition of sliding/opening doors (like a wooden cabinet) solve this?

Comment: Any hole in a wall will allow sound to pass through - in both directions.  An operating fan will make noise adding to the issue (although it's very white-noise-like which can be soothing and may drown out other noises). What does a "wooden cabinet" have to do with it?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Passing air while blocking sound is difficult. Beyond that, we probably can't say more unless you give us a lot more info, and perhaps not even then.

Answer (score 2):

This plan won't really work without a full circuit. You need exhaust *and* return, otherwise the return may be from somewhere undesirable (such as under the door or through leaks to the exterior). The fan will create low- and/or high-pressure regions and air will find a way.

I'd consider routing both through the attic or basement for sound attenuation, and look for internally-insulated ducting for further sound deadening. Openings in the wall will feel like windows with respect to sound and privacy.